# How to test for presence of a three-dimensional hash value in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a hash variable that can either exist in two ways: a one-dimensional hash like

```
myvar['level1']
```

which is always present, or a three-dimensional hash like

```
myvar['level1']['level2']['level3']
```

which may or may not be present. The level2 member may be there, sometimes with other members. Now if I want to test if the level3 member is present, I use code like

```
if myvar['level1']['level2'] != nil?
   if myvar['level1']['level2']['level3'] != nil?
      ....
```

because I will receive an error when I access the level3 member and there is no level2 member. I was wondering if there is a way to test for the presence of the level3 member without testing for the second member first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way:

```
def extract_values(h,keys)
  keys.reduce(h) { |g,k| ((g.is_a? Hash) ? g : {})[k] }
end

h = {a: {b: {c: "The End"} } }

extract_values(h,[])               #=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>"The End"}}}
extract_values(h,[:a])             #=> {:b=>{:c=>"The End"}}
extract_values(h,[:a, :b])         #=> {:c=>"The End"}
extract_values(h,[:a, :b, :c])     #=> "The End"
extract_values(h,[:a, :z, :c])     #=> nil
extract_values(h,[:a, :b, :c, :d]) #=> nil
```

Comment: This way i'm still stuch with two lines, it basically does the same as i test now but less readable.

Comment: This will not work, if you had `levels = %w{level1 level2 level3 level4}` while `h` did not have that level.

Comment: cootjie, as I see it, the main benefit of this approach is that it works with any number of levels.

Comment: It is a very good structural solution, something that should be part of the basic language structure imho. Added it to my default library!

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. "level3" exists just in relation to "level2", so it's mandatory to go through it before.
You can make the test look nicer, but you need to test the presence of "level2" first.
I can suggest a nicer version, but it's one among a lot

```
if l1 = mayvar['level1'] && l2 = l1['level2'] && l2['level3']
...
```